# How to get Roboto font in ViewPager with HoloEverywhere

Tags: android-holo-everywhere

I am trying to use Christophe Versieux's excellent HoloEverywhere library in a ViewPager which is used in a fragment.

If I have the following layout for my fragment ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:holo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Roboto Font" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" /></LinearLayout>
```

then the Roboto font appears in the TextView as I'd expect.

However, if the same TextView xml is in the view that the ViewPager inflates, the Roboto font doesn't appear in the pager's textview. It's just the default font.

What am I missing?